# Help I wanto download codeblocks from spesific reposity and it downloads from the normal repository

Tags: downloads, repository, code-blocks

I want to download CodeBlocks 13 from `ppa:pasgui/ppa` but it downloads 10 from the main repository. I used to download with `apt-get install codeblocks` They have the same filename. When I downloaded before it automatically downloaded from ppa:pasgui but now it downloads the 10.

Comment: Please mind your language *before* you post next time please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That PPA only offers packages for 14.04 and CodeBlocks 13 is available officially for 14.04 without any need for a PPA. So you must be using an older version. It seems to be the only PPA for CodeBlocks, so I think you'll have to use the binaries provided at [the original site](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26#linux64). See [this forum topic](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=19362.msg132304;topicseen), which mentions a still working ppa for CodeBlocks 13.12 on Ubuntu 12.04:

> Code::Blocks Ubuntu PPAs
>   Daily: https://launchpad.net/~damien-moore/+archive/codeblocks
>   Nightly: https://launchpad.net/~damien-moore/+archive/codeblocks-nightly

Of these, the Daily PPA seems to be more stable.

Comment: No i mean i added the ppa:pasgui/ppa     https://launchpad.net/~pasgui/+archive/ppa/ and it was very easy to install and worked with apt-get install codeblocks it was the 13.12svn9781-0ubuntu1~trusty version. it used to install that package. but now it installs from somewhere else. Maybe becouse they have same filename. Do you know how i can change the apt-get to install from there?

Comment: @user294777 What version of Ubuntu are you using? That PPA used to offer packages for older versions of Ubuntu, but it no longer does. If you are on any version of Ubuntu before 14.04, that PPA won't work. And on 14.04, that PPA isn't needed.

Comment: Ah crap i have 12.10 version maybe ill get new ubuntu then. Always have problems installing stuff myself manually

Comment: @user294777 in which case, use the binaries from the CodeBlocks website (link given in answer), or upgrade. Better to upgrade, 12.10 support ended on May 16. The mirrors for it will be shutting down soon.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu will simply pick the latest version of a package available to it. You can see the versions available to it at any given time using the `apt-cache policy <package>` command. I don't have the PPA installed and I'm on 14.04 but here's what I see:

```
$ apt-cache policy codeblocks
codeblocks:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 13.12-3
  Version table:
     13.12-3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

If you have more than one version, you can force the installed version:

```
sudo apt-get install codeblocks:13.12-3
```

But as soon as you sudo apt-get dist-upgrade, it'll go back to the latest version. You can get around this by pinning the package but I'll not go into that unless you really need it. It can cause more problems in the long term.